# Why is the Minkowski sum of an open set and a singleton open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a normed space and open $A \subset X $ and   $x\in X$.
>   Prove that $A+x:=\{a+x : a \in A            \} $.

It seems trivial but I do want to prove rigorously.
I have tried as follows:

Take an element $y \in A+x $. So , $ y=a+x , \ \  a\in A$.  Since $A$ is open,  $ \exists B(a,\delta) \subset A . $

Can I directly jump to the step $ B(a+x, \delta) \subset A+x ? $ Does this $ \delta$  work for both arguments or do I need to find different $\delta$'s  for different inclusions? How do I proceed?

Comment: Always use the definitions. Here, you cannot proceed without the def'n of B(a,d). Definitions are not just rules. They are tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is right. You take $y\in B(a+x, \delta)$, then $\|y-(a+x)\|<\delta$, this implies $y-x\in B(a,\delta) \subset A$. This follows $y-x =a'
\in A$, and then $y=x+a' \in x+A$. Actually, $x+A$ is the translation of $A$ with direction $x$.