# Translation of an open set is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How to I show that if A is an open set then $A+b=\{a+b : a \in A\}$ is an open set? Intuitively I understand but I'm having a hard time writing it.

I know that since $A$ is open then $\forall a \in A \exists V_\epsilon(a) \subseteq A$. Then I want to say that $V_\epsilon(a+b) \subseteq A+b$ but I'm not sure how to justify it.

Comment: Show that $V_r(x)+b=V_r(x+b)$ for each $x$ in the space and $r>0$.

Comment: Another idea is to see that $A+b$ is the image of $A$ by the diffemorphism $\varphi(p)=p+b$.

Comment: Is there a definition for adding a number to a interval? Intuitively I would say $V_\epsilon(a) +b =(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) +b = (a+b-\epsilon, a+b+\epsilon) = V_\epsilon(a+b)$ but i'm not sure if that skips steps or not. Also how would i show its a subset of $A+b$?

Comment: @LTM - your definition of "adding a number to an interval" agrees with the definition you give in the question for "adding a number to a set". It also suggests that you have $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, which you should mention if it is true.

Comment: It is generally true that if $X \subset A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $X + b \subset A+b$. Proving it is very close to the definition: Prove that if $x \in X+b$, then $x \in A+b$.

Comment: See also: [Why is the Minkowski sum of an open set and a singleton open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2191383)